# Angular 2 - Use Component selector to display json array value

Tags: angular

I am attempting to display an array value using the component selector without success.  Currently, the component selector will display every value in the template/model. I would like to display a single value(taxes) of the model.

**userAccount.component.html**

```
            <div *ngFor="let userAccount of UserAccounts" [class.active]="userAccount === selectedUser" (click)="onSelect(userAcccount)">
               <div class= 'col-md-12'> 
                     <input class = "form-control"[(ngModel)] = "userAccount.firstName" placeholder= "First Name" /> 
                     <input class = "form-control"[(ngModel)] = "userAccount.LastName" placeholder= "Last Name" />  
                         <input class = "form-control"[(ngModel)] = "userAccount.email" placeholder= "Email" />  
                      <br>    <div class= 'col-md-12'>Region</div> <hr>
                           <input class = "form-control"[(ngModel)] = "userAccount.region" placeholder= "Region" />  
                             <input class = "form-control"[(ngModel)] = "userAccount.taxes" placeholder= "Tax Rate" />  

     <br>     
       <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <br>
        <button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
        <button (click)="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
```

**estimate-detail.component.html**

```
 <tr *ngFor ="let userAccount of UserAccounts">
          <td  class="table-borderless" colSpan="4" class="text-right"><b>Tax</b></td>
          <app-userAccount>{{userAccount.taxes}}</app-userAccount>       
      </tr>
```

Comment: I think you are using `{{userAccount.taxes}}` with the component. can you use just `{{userAccount.taxes}}` instead of `<app-userAccount>{{userAccount.taxes}}</app-userAccount>`

Comment: Currently your question is quite unclear (at least for me). Could you add to your question how the current output is and how the expected output would be.

Comment: @Jijo Cleetus Believe it or not, I tried that and it did not work initially, but now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the template for the UserAccount component is going to provide the necessary markup to add the taxes value to the table row, I would simply place the interpolation markup for userAccount.taxes within another table cell.

```
<td class="table-borderless" colspan="n">{{ userAccount.taxes }}</td>
```

If the template for the UserAccount component **is** going to wrap the userAccount.taxes in a table cell, then I would pass the value by binding it to a variable in my component that implements the @Input decorator.

```
<app-userAccount [taxes]='userAccount.taxes'></app-userAccount>

export class UserAccount {
  @Input() taxes: String;
  rest of component...
```